# filter in a nested array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to have an array that return certain property base on the checked property and also want to filter out the levels of the selected skills as possible

```
const data = [
      {
        "name": "Beginner",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Intermediate",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Professional",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
```

The function return the checked skills, but also return all the level objects with it

```
levelwithskills = data.map(level =>
              Object.assign({}, level, {
              skills: level.skills.filter(skill => skill.checked)
            })
          )
```

i expect to get the result in format

```
   [
      {
        "name": "Beginner",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Intermediate",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After mapping, `filter` by whether an item has any `skills`:

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Beginner",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Intermediate",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Professional",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
]
levelwithskills = data
  .map(level => ({ ...level, skills: level.skills.filter(skill => skill.checked) }))
  .filter(({ skills }) => skills.length)
console.log(levelwithskills);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
const levelwithskills = data.reduce((arr, level) => {
  // filter skills
  let skills = level.skills.filter(({ checked }) => checked);
  // check length of filtered skills if greater than 0 then push into array
  skills.length && arr.push({ ...level, skills });
  // return array reference
  return arr
  // set initial value as an empty array for the result
}, [])
```

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Beginner",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Intermediate",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Professional",
    "skills": [{
        "name": "Skill 1",
        "checked": false
      },
      {
        "name": "Skill 2",
        "checked": false
      }
    ]
  },
];

const levelwithskills = data.reduce((arr, level) => {
  let skills = level.skills.filter(({ checked }) => checked);
  skills.length && arr.push({ ...level, skills });
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(levelwithskills)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
      {
        "name": "Beginner",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Intermediate",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Professional",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
    
    let newData = data.map(d=>({
      ...d,
      skills: d.skills.filter(fd=>fd.checked)
    })).filter(afd=>afd.skills.length)
    console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can do this as

```js
const data = [
      {
        "name": "Beginner",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Intermediate",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Professional",
        "skills": [
          {
            "name": "Skill 1",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Skill 2",
            "checked": false
          }
        ]
      },
    ]




let filteredData=[]
data.map((obj)=>{
  obj.skills.map((innerObj)=>{
      if(innerObj.checked===true){
  filteredData.push({name:obj.name,
                  skills:innerObj})
      } 
  })
})
 

  console.log(filteredData)
```